# extract text between single quotes and between spaces in a string using C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file with lines in this format:

```
'F1 TEXT'                   59   59      2    2      1    1    'X'    /
```

I was able to use `getline()` to read individual lines. Now, I need to get the strings between single quotes (`'F1 TEXT'` and `'X'`), as well as the numbers delimited by space, into an array or something similar. Any guidance on the appropriate functions or algorithms would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
std::ifstream file(file_name);
std::string line;
if (file.is_open()) {
    while (std::getline(file, line)) 
    {
        // using printf() in all tests for consistency
        printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
        contents.push_back(line);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Add the variable declarations for the variables you want to be parsed.

Answer (score 3):

After extracting a line, you can put it into a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and then extract the individual values from it using `operator>>`, using the [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) I/O manipulator to handle the reading of the quoted strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

struct Data
{
    std::string value1;
    int value2;
    int value3;
    int value4;
    int value5;
    int value6;
    int value7;
    std::string value8;
    char value9;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Data &data)
{
    in >> std::quoted(data.value1, '\x27')
       >> data.value2
       >> data.value3
       >> data.value4
       >> data.value5
       >> data.value6
       >> data.value7
       >> std::quoted(data.value8, '\x27')
       >> data.value9;
    return in;
}

...

std::ifstream file(file_name);

std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) 
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    Data data;
    if (iss >> data) {
        // use data as needed...
    }
}
```